# Как правильно быстро обновлять UIView в ios?

Tags: ios, imageview

У меня есть приложение, в котором к таймеру (`NSTimer`) привязано обновление картинки на экране. По задумке, обновлять нужно картинку со скоростью 15-30 раз в секунду. В моём коде, после 10 секунд нормальной работы скорость падает, и картинка уже обновляется 1-2 раза в секунду. 
Код примерно такой:

**ViewController.m**

```
   #import "ViewController.h"
   #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

   @implementation ViewController

   @synthesize myImage; //картинка 
   @synthesize imageView; 
   @synthesize timer; //таймер
   @synthesize rect; 

/*этот метод создаёт таймер. Таймер вызывает метод setPicture каждые 0.04 
секунды */
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender{

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.04 target:self selector:@selector(setPicture) userInfo:nil repeats:true];
} 

/*этот метод генерирует случайную картинку и устанавливает её на экран */
-(void)setPicture { 
if(imageView!=NULL) //обнуляем imageView 
{        
    imageView = NULL; //Убрать"!
}
int width = 352; //размеры картинки
int height = 288;

size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4; //
uint8_t* pixels = (uint8_t*)malloc(bufferLength); //выделение памяти под массив пикселей
for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) { //заполнение случайными пикселями
    pixels[i] = rand() % 255;
}

CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * 4, space, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); // указатель void * __nullable data

CGImageRef toCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage * uiimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:toCGImage]; //создание картинки из массива пикселей

CGImageRelease(toCGImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
free(pixels);

myImage = uiimage;
//

rect = self.view.bounds; //Вынесли в член класса

if(imageView == NULL)
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    imageView.image = myImage; //присвоение картинки к imageView
    [self.view addSubview:imageView]; //установка картинки поверх всего

}
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property NSTimer * timer;
@property UIImage* myImage;
@property  UIImageView *imageView; 
@property  CGRect rect; //прямоугольное графическое пространство

-(IBAction)start:(id)sender;

-(void)setPicture;

@end
```

Код  `-(IBAction)start` привязан к кнопке в сториборде. Как уже было сказано, обновление `UIView`, после 10 секунд работы существенно замедляется. Есть мнение, что я неправильно обнуляю `imageView` (2-ая строка метода `setPicture`), но если так, то неясно как сделать это правильно.

**Вопрос:** как правильно обновлять `UIImageView`, чтобы приложение не продуцировало утечку памяти и картинка обновлялась с хорошей скоростью, то есть 20-30 кадров в секунду?

Comment: когда вы делаете addSubview родительский вью становится владельцем вашего imageView и после этого вью не обнуляется когда вы делаете imageView = null. через несколько секунд у вас там сотни изображений. если никто раньше не ответит напишу как исправить когда до компьютера доберусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, `self.imageView` надо не только занулять, но ещё и `removeFromSuperview`, иначе на вьюхе будут стековаться картинки до бесконечности.

Во-вторых, раз уже прозвучал вопрос про **правильно**: для таких целей наиболее правильно использовать `CADisplayLink`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (nonatomic) CFAbsoluteTime lastTime;
@property (nonatomic) CFAbsoluteTime timeSum;

- (void)startDisplayLink {
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    self.lastTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink {
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink {
    CFAbsoluteTime time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    self.timeSum = self.timeSum + (self.lastTime - time);
    while (self.timeSum > FRAME_DURATION) {
        self.timeSum = self.timeSum - FRAME_DURATION;
        [self nextPicture];
    }
    self.lastTime = time;
}
```

Так же рекомендовал бы рендерить картинки в бэкграунде, но это уже другая задача, по-сложнее. Тонкое место тут так же `while (self.timeSum > FRAME_DURATION) {` - это значит, что может за один шаг несколько картинок нарендериться, приём одна перепишет другую. Можно в этом while, например, просто считать количество фреймов, а  вотом загружать именно нужный фрейм (или не загружать вовсе, если смены фреймов не было).

Comment: Даже лучше вообще не занулять и не убирать imageView, а вместо этого просто если imageView уже существует, то просто выставлять ему `imageView.image = myImage;`.

Comment: Как интересно!
а мой код как оптимальнее всего переписать? А то я не очень даже понимаю, пока что, в какое место вставить removeFromSuperview.

Comment: removeFromSuperview  перед imageView = NULL; - это решит проблему с памятью и зависанием

Comment: всё классно вы знаете. Спасибо помогли.